# What is behind this property naming of the model generated by EF

Tags: c#

I've made my models from existing database using

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ...
```

The following model is one of them:

```
public partial class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Link { get; set; } = null!;

    public int SourceId { get; set; }

    public int? Cid { get; set; }

    public string Ctype { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }

    public int Visits { get; set; }

    public virtual Category? CidNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual Source? Source { get; set; }  
}
```

I'm wondering why CidNavigation and not Category?
Because as you can see We don't have a SourceIdNavigation We have "Source" and the source_id column is just like the cid and the realtion is many-to-one.
So why double standard?
Is it OK to rename it to Category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it has to do with duplicate names, since cid is already used, it adds "navigation" but it knows that source_id is related to a table named source, so it names it source since that isn't used yet.

Comment: "duplicate names" - what duplicate names? _"since cid is already used"_ - and? If EF is discovers `Cid` as key column then the navigation property would be named `C` not `Cid` - that is common convention (which works for `Source` - `SourceId` pair).